# Tagged Custom Vaadin Component is not added to the MainView layout

Tags: javascript, java, html, vaadin, web-component

I'm trying to add my custom vis component to MainView VerticalLayout. But it is rendered above the layout and the layout itself contains an empty component tag.

##### Custom component code

Here I'm tagging my component as "div"

```
@JsModule("./visjs-test.js")
@NpmPackage(value = "vis", version = "0.110.0")
@Tag("div")
public class VisJs extends Component {

    public VisJs(List<VisJsEdge> edges, List<VisJsNode> nodes) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectWriter owForEdges = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        ObjectWriter owForNodes = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

        String jsonEdges = owForEdges.writeValueAsString(edges);
        String jsonNodes = owForNodes.writeValueAsString(nodes);

        getElement().executeJs("window.initThree($0, $1, $2)", this, jsonEdges, jsonNodes);
    }
}
```

##### visjs-test.js:

Here I'm filling nodes and edge of future network and trying to render it

```
import {DataSet, Network} from "vis";

class VisJsTest {
    init(element, edges, nodes) {
        this.element = element;

        var loadedNodes = JSON.parse(nodes);
        
        var _this = this;
        var step;
        for (step = 0; step < loadedNodes.length; step++) {
            loadedNodes[step] = this.fillNode(loadedNodes[step]);
        }
        this.nodes = new DataSet(loadedNodes);
        
        var loadedEdges = JSON.parse(edges);
        for (step = 0; step < loadedEdges.length; step++) {
            loadedEdges[step] = this.fillEdge(loadedEdges[step]);
        }
        this.edges = new DataSet(loadedEdges);

        this.container = document.getElementById("outlet");
        
        this.data = {
            nodes: this.nodes,
            edges: this.edges,
        };
        var options = {};
        this.network = new Network(this.container, this.data, options);
}
```

##### Rendered HTML

```
<div id="outlet">
   <!-- Network is here, but not must be -->
   <div class="vis-network" tabindex="900" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <canvas style="position: relative; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1260" height="563"></canvas>
   </div>
   <flow-container-root-2521314 id="ROOT-2521314" style="">
      <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="padding spacing" id="mainview" style="width: 100%;">
         ...
         <vaadin-button tabindex="0" role="button">Add node</vaadin-button>
         <vaadin-horizontal-layout theme="spacing">
            <vaadin-upload target="VAADIN/dynamic/resource/3/c968ce30-4fc1-4e36-8d06-ddba9ecfbfd1/upload"></vaadin-upload>
            <vaadin-button disabled="" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" role="button">Load data to XML</vaadin-button>
         </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
         ... 
         <div></div> <!-- Network must be here -->
         ...
      </vaadin-vertical-layout>
   </flow-container-root-2521314>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your component is not setting "id" of the element. And in your case there is accidentally other div with id=outlet, and your JavaScript `document.getElementById("outlet");` finds it and uses it as element where it builds the Network.

I would do it this way

```
@JsModule("./visjs-test.js")
@NpmPackage(value = "vis", version = "0.110.0")
@Tag("div")
public class VisJs extends Composite<Div> {

    public VisJs(List<VisJsEdge> edges, List<VisJsNode> nodes) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String id=randomId(10);
        setId();
        ...
        getElement().executeJs("window.initThree($0, $1, $2)", this, jsonEdges, jsonNodes, id);
    }
    
    private String randomId(int chars) {
        int limit = (10 * chars) - 1;
        String key = "" + rand.nextInt(limit);
        key = String.format("%" + chars + "s", key).replace(' ', '0');
        return "vis-" + key;
    }
```

And naturally update the `initThree` function you have set to `window` to use that `id` parameter.

You need to have unique id for each component instance. This way you can create multiple components on the same view. Otherwise new instances would ruin the old ones.